# Why are these states not displaying the data when the data exists with the usmap package?

Tags: r, usmap

I'm trying to plot election results on the US map with the usmap package but even though the dataset is complete, I get plot that shows missing values for some states. The states are greyed out and I'm not sure why this is happening..

[image]

```r
plot_usmap(data=data_total,values='percent_biden')+
  scale_fill_continuous(low='red',high='blue',name='Percent for Biden')+
  theme(legend.position='right')+
  ggtitle(paste("Total Popular Vote of Final Results"))
```

[image]

Comment: It will be easier to help if you include your code.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly assuming that `usmap` will *infer* any format for state names. For instance, both of these produce a working map,

```r
usmap::plot_usmap(data=data.frame(state=c("alabama","new york"),s=c(5,15)), values="s")
usmap::plot_usmap(data=data.frame(state=c("AL","NY"),s=c(5,15)), values="s")
```

[image: two states, take 1]

whereas inferring from your pic of data, you are trying

```r
usmap::plot_usmap(data=data.frame(state=c("alabama","new-york"),s=c(5,15)), values="s")
#                                                       ^ dash, not space
```

[image: alabama alone]

So I believe you need to clean up your data and fix your state names.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems obvious now haha

Comment: Yeah, notice that your "empty" states all have spaces in their names, that was my first clue.